# Logic subject-reductio ad absurdum

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can you solve this using method **reductio ad absurdum**?

$\text{1})\ A ↔ (\neg B v C)$

$\neg A$

$\text{______________}$

$\neg B$

$\text{2})\ \neg(R∧ (S v T))$

$\text{3})\ R∧\neg T$

$S$

$\text{______________}$

$\neg R∧ S$

Comment: 1)A↔ (¬ B v C)
¬ A  
¬ B

 2)¬(R∧ (S v T))

 3)R∧¬ T
   S
¬R∧ S